# Customizing Android BluetoothLeGatt example and send data via BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, send

I have to say at first that i am new to android programming. I am trying to send simple data (a short string) to a BLE peripheral device via Android. Therefore i customized the BluetoothLeGatt example from

http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/project.html

I replaced the Gatt Services List in the gatt_services_characteristics.xml with a text field for incoming data and below a EditText and a "send" button. The code is the following:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/gatt_services_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/sendText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/gatt_services_list"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="SEND"
        android:onClick="sendData"/>
```

I also commented out the function displayGattServices(List gattServices) in DeviceControlActivity.java and wrote a function for the button click as below:

```
public void sendData(View v) {
    value = textField.getText().toString();
    byte [] strBytes = value.getBytes();

    mGattServicesList.setText(text + "\n>" + value);
    text = text + "\n>" + value;

    clearUI();
}
```

I now want to implement a simple way to send the data typed in the EditText. The data just shall be shown in a terminal.

I searched for a solution, but i didn't fully understand the concept of the Gatt Characteristic which i am afraid i have to use for this. I am programming with Android Studio 1.4.1 and using API 18 and higher.

How can i send the data in an easy way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the service and characteristic of the device that you intend to send the data to? You have to specify the service and characteristic when you send the data, and (depending on the roles of the peripheral and phone) for the data to be accepted that characteristic needs to be writable.

Comment: My BLE peripheral device provides 4 characteristics:
0x1800 - Generic Access
0x180A - Device Information Service
0x1801 - Generic Attribute
0x1101 - Serial Port

I don't know which one of those i have to use, but i assume it is Serial Port. 

In the end i want a bidirectional transmission between the phone and the peripheral device, while the phone sends some control commands the peripheral just gives back some sensor data.

Answer (score -1):

Android BluetoothLeGatt example already customized to Send and Receive via UART. See
https://github.com/danasf/hm10-android-arduino

Comment: Please target what is useful in the link you provided (some code for example)